# Handle the payload of a POST request from Node-RED with deno fresh framework

Tags: request, httphandler, deno, freshjs

When I sent a POST request to an endpoint with node-red I can't find a way to access the data that I sent in msg.payload with the POST handler that I made with deno fresh.

I tried to get the data from the req.body but it returns:

`ReadableStream { locked: false }`

so I printed the hole request of the handler and the data aren't anywhere in the request.

The handler code is the following:

```
import { Handlers, HandlerContext } from "$fresh/server.ts";

export const handler: Handlers = {
    async POST(req: Request, ctx: HandlerContext){
        const payload = await req.body
        console.log(payload)
        return new Response(payload)
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the POST handler code? You probably need a `for await...of` loop to access the data in the stream.

Comment: @Zwiers I added the POST handler code. The documentation for the fresh framework shows only examples for GET requests but I think that POST and more request are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is in the request body, but it has to be read from the ReadableStream in chunks of bytes. You can do this with a `for await` loop:

```
for await (const chunk of req.body) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

So if for example you wanted to just log the data, the handler would look something like this:

```
export const handler: Handlers = {
  async POST(req: Request, ctx: HandlerContext){
      const payload = req.body

      if (payload === null) {
        return new Response("Invalid request: body is null");
      }

      const decoder = new TextDecoder()
      for await (const chunk of payload) {
        // decode the bytes into a string and print it
        console.log(decoder.decode(chunk))
      }

      return new Response(payload)
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the data and saved them to a database. The only problem is that I can't send the payload variable as a Response but I don't mind that I just sent a text.